# Is Ackerman steering solved?

Tags: suspension, steering

I heard of jeantaud mechanism of steering.

does it accomplish the right steering everytime? aren't tyres slipping in any situation? I mean, is it the definitive solution to the Ackerman steering or just a good approximation? in case the jeantaud mechanism isn't, there exist a definitive solution to this problem?

Does this solution work even if the vehicle has got suspension? I mean, if suspensions are present, do they create problems with this hypothetical steering? 
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some reading, it appears Jeantaud's mechanism uses shorter lever arms to acheive a more accurate *effect*.  However, both mechanisms (Ackerman and Jeantaud) are sensitive to a number of things, wheelbase, speed, and body roll from suspension travel - namely toe changes (and to a lesser extent camber changes).  Mechanically these mechanisms are quite the same, with some argument about which "inventor" had a better implementation.

I don't consider the problem "solved" from a theory standpoint, but these mecahnisms are widely used and probably good enough for a practical manufacturing and a cost/benefit standpoint.  What's reasonable on a Ford Sierra is not what you find on a Ferrari or F1 car.